# wordpress max_user_connections error script optimization

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance

On my wordpress site, this error always persist.

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1226): User 'u631047969_vins' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 15) in /home/u631047969/domains/vupoll.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1633

On my self developed theme, I am using angularjs for data binding. I know this will be deprecated and I am not sure if this is the cause of it.

Other thing is about my hosting. My max_user_connections set to my hosting is only 15. Is this value too low that made this error occur?

My website doesn't even have huge traffic. I only have around 300 monthly visitors.

Does Wordpress have good practices in using custom queries that I do not use?
Should I stop using angularjs to my site?
Or the 15 max_user_connection is just too low?

Any help or tips will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any sort of "connection pooling"?